# How to get two numerical values from a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a string like this :

> X LIMITED COMPANY (52100000/58447000)

I want to extract **X LIMITED COMPANY**, **52100000** and **58447000** seperately.

I'm extracting **X LIMITED COMPANY** like this :

```
companyName = Regex.Match(mystring4, @"[a-zA-Z\s]+").Value.Trim();
```

But I'm stuck with extracting numbers, they can be 1, 2 or large numbers in the example. Can you show me how to extract those numbers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regular expressions with alternative `|` (*or*):

- Either word symbols (but not digits) `[\w-[\d]][\w\s-[\d]]+)`
- Digits only `([0-9]+)`

E.g.

```
string mystring4 = @"AKASYA CAM SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ(52100000 / 58447000)";

string[] values = Regex
  .Matches(mystring4, @"([\w-[\d]][\w\s-[\d]]+)|([0-9]+)")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value.Trim())
  .ToArray();
```

Test

```
// X LIMITED COMPANY
// 52100000
// 58447000  
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, values));
```

I suggested changing the initial pattern `[a-zA-Z\s]+` into `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+` in order to skip matches which contain separators only (e.g. `"    "`)

Comment: This didn't work,  this just splitted X LIMITED COMPANY in a wrong way. Like X LIMI -  ED COMP - ANY

Comment: @jason: no, the pattern `"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+"` means *start* with `[a-zA-Z]` *contain* `[a-zA-Z\s]+`; please, notice usual `+`, not `+?` - *greedy* matching (i.e. match *as many as possible*), so `"X LIMITED COMPANY"` will be returned. I've run my sample and I've seen

Comment: My actual string is : AKASYA CAM SANAYİ VE TİCARET LİMİTED ŞİRKETİ, so it includes Turkish characters, that's why it fails. How can I add Turkish characters into that regular expression. Thanks.

Comment: @jason: in this case you have to change the pattern into `[\w][\w\s]+`: you want any word letter `\w` not just `[a-zA-Z]` ones

Comment: `\w` includes 0-9 so the `|([0-9]+)` becomes redundant. Skip it and it'll capture all groups *between* non-word characters.

Comment: `[\w-[\d]]` will also match underscores, use `[\w-[\d_]]` if you want to avoid them. An easier way is to use `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter.

Comment: @jason might have been useful had you mentioned that in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using named groups:

```
var s = "X LIMITED COMPANY (52100000 / 58447000)";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<CompanyName>[^\(]+)\((?<Num1>\d+)\s*/\s*(?<Num2>\d+)\)");

var match = regex.Match(s);
var companyName = match.Groups["CompanyName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is fixed, you could try this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<name>[^\(]+)\((?<n1>\d+)/(?<n2>\d+)\)");

var match = regex.Match(input);
var companyName = match.Groups["name"].Value;
var number1 = Convert.ToInt64(match.Groups["n1"].Value);
var number2 = Convert.ToInt64(match.Groups["n2"].Value);
```

This matches everything up to the open parentheses and puts it into a named group "name". Then it matches two numbers within parentheses, separated by "/" and puts them into groups named "n1" and "n2" respectively.